# Free and Open Source Workflow engine with GUI diagram editor and embeddable API

Tags: diagram, workflow, editor, process-control

I'm searching for a Workflow engine that have a visual editor for creating diagrams, and a library that can be embedded in a solid webapp framework (Django, Spring...)

The solutions I have valuated until now and discarded are:

- Activiti: it will be perfect, but the editor does not allow you to define variables for an automatic task
- Camunda: it seems you can't define custom types for variables, validation of process is very limited, and builtin types are only string, list (of strings, I suppose), map (of string,string I suppose) and script (?). No long, double, boolean, byte.
- YAWL: it will be perfect, but it's really bugged, the source code is bad and it's practically a dead project.

Comment: Could you please explain more about your need "define variables for an automatic task". I have used Activiti several times, and I was using variables, and automatic tasks.